# no matching handler method found when upgrading from spring mvc 3.0.7-RELEASE to 4.1.7-RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portlet

I'm currently stuck with spring mvc about event between my portlets.

Actually, i have two portlet which have been upgraded to spring 4.1.7, and when I try to exchange an object between them, this exception comes up :

```
 org.springframework.web.portlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No matching handler method found for portlet request: mode 'view', phase 'EVENT_PHASE', parameters map[[empty]]
```

The problem here is that when i back on spring 3.0.7-RELEASE with the portlet which supposed to receive the event, no more problem. But I would like to have all my portlet at the same spring version.

I import those jar for spring 4 :

```
spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
```

and for spring 3.0.7 :

```
the same jar as above (version 3.0.7 instead of course) plus spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
```

On my portlet which receive the event I have this config in the portlet.xml

```
<portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
<filter>
    <filter-name>filter-name</filter-name>
    <filter-class>.path.to.portlet.filter.MapperEventFilter</filter-class>
    <lifecycle>EVENT_PHASE</lifecycle>
</filter>
   .
   .
   .
```

By the way I import also portlet-2.0 api in both portlets and I use java 8.

I wanted to know if anyone faced the same problem or have an idea about this problem. I don't know why changing spring version gives me this problem with handler mapping.
Tell me if I am not clear on something.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable in your `"yourPortletName"-portlet.xml`:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

or if you want to go with `.java` based configuration on class level:

```
@EnableWebMvc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already try what you proposed and it did not work for me